# google is not defined when it's added dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm currently loading the Google Maps API using JavaScript like so:

```
// Private methods
  function loadApi() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onerror = function(e) {
      exit('MarvMap: Unable to load Google Map API, please check the URL.');
    };
    script.onload = function () {
      if (this.options.debug) console.log('MarvMap (Debug): Google Map API loaded, using: ' + this.options.api.key);
    }.call(this);
    script.src = this.options.api.url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
```

This loads the script and ads it before the closing `</head>` tag. However the script it loads appears to load additional scripts so it's not ready to use straight away.

Here you can see that i'm calling the above function first, and then trying to use the Google Maps API:

```
// Public methods
MarvMap.prototype.init = function() {
  loadApi.call(this);

  // Setup map options and map reference
  initMapOptions.call(this);

  // Build the map
  build.call(this);
};
```

However im getting an error saying `google is not defined` on the line marked below:

```
function initMapOptions() {
    this.mapReference = new google.maps; // Error here
    this.map_options = {
      map_type: function(i) {
        if (this.mapReference.MapTypeId[(i-1)] !== undefined) {
          return this.mapReference.MapTypeId[(i-1)];
        } else { exit(this.errors.map_type(i)); }
      }.bind(this)
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delay api usage while i wait for some file (or multiple files) to load i would use something like:

```
loadApi(this);
ensureApiIsLoaded();


function ensureApiIsLoaded(){
    if(typeof google == 'undefined'){
        setTimeout(ensureApiIsLoaded, 125);
        return;
    } else {
        callbackGoesHere(); //initMapOptions?
    }
};
```

regarding your while loop:

```
    while (typeof google != 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(function() { }, 1000);
    }
    google;
```

- you initiate the script loading -> api isn't ready, obviously
- the while condition will evaluate to 'false' -> body of while loop is dismissed
- google is still undefined because there wasn't any time to actually load the lib in between ordering that the script file be acquired and the attempted usage
  -> error.